# VBA UDF index match run time error 424: Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a UDF that reads scores from another workbook that has worksheet called "sh_scores"  and returns the value based on date(rows) and sector(columns) using index match. The UDF function is returning #VALUE and when I debug the Index and match separately am getting the error #424 above. Kindly, I will appreciate any help I could get. Below is my code:

```
Function getScores (iDate, Sector) As Double
Dim Scores As Double
Dim lastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim appExcel As Application
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook 
Dim sh_Scores As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


Set appExcel = New Application
appExcel.Visible = False

Set objWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("I:\myFolder\Project10\Performance.xlsb")
Set sh_SourceScores = objWorkbook.Worksheets("sh_Scores")

lastRow = sh_SourceScores.Range("A2", sh_SourceScores.Range("A"& rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows).Rows.Count
LastCol = sh_SourceScores.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   Scores = Application.Index(sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:O337"), Application.Match(iDate, sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:A337"), 0), Application.Match(Sector, sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:O1"), 0))

getScores = Scores

objWorkbook.Close
appExcel.Quit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Function
```

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: The `lastrow` line should be `End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: This is the line where the error appears:    Scores = Application.Index(sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:O337"), Application.Match(iDate, sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:A337"), 0), Application.Match(Sector, sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:O1"), 0))

Comment: Before that line insert `debug.print Application.Match(iDate, sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:A337"), 0)` and similar for the other match and report what shows up in the immediate window.

Comment: Thanks  @SJR. Using debug.print was able to identify the error 2042. The function worked when i changed the function to read:                                              
           Function getScores (iDate as Date, Sector) As Double  and Match function as follows: Application.Match(CDate(iDate), sh_SourceScores.Range("A1:A337"), 0). Thanks a lot for your help in pointing me to the right direction.